# Multiple methods for action in API Platform

Tags: api-platform.com

I'm writing a custom action and I need to make it available for both `GET` (collection) and `POST` methods.

My annotation looks like this.

```
/**
 * @Route(
 *     name="api_entity_custom",
 *     path="/entity/custom",
 *     defaults={
 *      "_api_resource_class"=Entity::class,
 *      "_api_collection_operation_name"="EntityCustom"
 *     }
 * )
 * @Method("GET")
 */
```

That works for GET, but when I add POST then I only see GET in docs (swagger)

```
@Method({"GET", "POST"})
```

If I change the order then I see `POST` but not `GET`

```
@Method({"POST", "GET"})
```

Is it possible to do this? How?

EDIT:
I'm using a structure like this

```
//Path/To/Entity/Action/EntityCustomAction.php  
class EntityCustomAction
    {
        /**
         * @Route(
         *     name="api_entity_custom",
         *     path="/entity/custom",
         *     defaults={
         *      "_api_resource_class"=Entity::class,
         *      "_api_collection_operation_name"="EntityCustom"
         *     }
         * )
         * @Method("GET")
         */

        public function __invoke($data)
{
...
```

which is enabled in routing

```
entity:
   resource: '@EntityBundle/Action/'
   type:     'annotation'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in following way:

```
Action 1:

/**
 * @Route("/data/save", name="data_save")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function dataSaveViewAction()
{
    // code here...
}

Action 2:

/**
 * @Route("/data/save", name="data_save")
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function dataSaveAction(Request $request)
{
    // code here ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are using the same name for both actions. However, the name of a route must be unique. If not, API-Platform won't display it. You should do something like this :

```
    Action 1:

/**
 * @Route("/data/save", name="data_save_get") // Choose a unique name
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function dataSaveViewAction()
{
    // code here...
}

Action 2:

/**
 * @Route("/data/save", name="data_save_post") // same here
 * @Method({"POST"})
 */
public function dataSaveAction(Request $request)
{
    // code here ...
}
```